# Definition of an open set clarification.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Could anyone tell me if $B(x;r)$ is required to be a proper subset for $Y$ to be open in the definition below? Or, could it be a subset?

Definiton: Let $Y\subset X$ A point $x\in X$ is an interior point of $Y$ if there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x;r)\subset Y$.

Comment: No. Just a subset. Many people use $\subset$ for $\subseteq$.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $B(x;r)$ stand for the open ball around $x\in X$ of radius $r\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular $X$ is a metric space.

No, $B(x;r)$ is not assumed to be a proper subset. In particular if you take $X=Y=B(x;r)$ itself then clearly $B(x;r)$ is not a proper subset, while $x$ is an interior point of $Y$. And sometimes finding a proper open ball around $x$ is impossible, e.g. when $Y=\{x\}$ is open itself.